How to price the convexity premium on a bond?
It appears to be the case that convexity is a benefit that investors are often willing to pay a premium for. How does this factor into the bond's theoretical price? And why is it not part of the original equation for computing a bond's price given a yield (with discounted cash flows)?

Think you are confusing price and value. They are not the same. For example low coupon Gilts also have a tax advantage to domestic investors due to no capital gains tax, on capital gains of the bond..I don't see tax in the bond price equation. The effects are subsumed in the price/yield that the market marks it at.

The relationship between price and yield is purely mechanical- the yield is just the discount rate that makes the present value equal to the price.  There is no judgment about convexity within the calculation.
What you are asking is how to figure out the value of convexity in long dated bonds. Here is a simplified model: imagine a 5% flat yield curve so that bonds of all maturities yield 5%. Now imagine a parallel, one standard deviation move in yields (calculated from historical or implied volatilities), and let’s say this is 6bp.  We then propose that the expected p/l of all bonds should be the same( for a given dv01 position) . For example the p/l of a very short dated bond will simply be 6xdv01, but the p/l of the long dated bond will be 6xdv01+ a convexity benefit. The point is, the market will increase the price of the long dated bond to offset the convexity benefit of a one standard deviation move, summed over the life of the long dated bond.  (Note this is simplified-the one standard deviation is different for different maturities , and yield curve does not move in parallel all the time.  But that’s the principle).
